# How to call function in primary template for a specialization of the class template?

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a normal function in a class template, when I specialize the class template, could I call the normal function as well?

Such as I have a template class

```cpp
template<int i>
class A
{
public:
    void func() {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And its specialization

```cpp
template<>
class A<1>
{
public:
    void func1() {
        cout << "A1" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now in main

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto a1 = A<1>();
    a1.func1();
    a1.func();   //<--- here
}
```

How could I call `a1.func()`?

Comment: `a1` doesn't have a `func`, you can't call it.

Comment: You seem to believe that the specialization somehow extends the primary template, or something like that. This is not the case - the specialization replaces the primary template. If you don't add `func` to the specialization, it won't have one.

Answer (score 1):

The class `A<1>` *doesn't have* a member `func`. The primary template is ignored when you specialise. If you want it to behave like inheritance, you could use inheritance.

```
class BaseA
{
public:
    void func() {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<int>
class A : public BaseA {};

template<>
class A<1> : public BaseA 
{
public:
    void func1() {
        cout << "A1" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now `A<1>` inherits `func` from `BaseA`, and `A<2>` doesn't have `func1`, but does have `func`.